# Squish Record and play in python

Tags: python-3.x, squish

While  recording activities in an application through squish in python, I want some wait time in between consecutive activities.

Which function should I use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`snooze`](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#snooze-function) function to suspend test execution for a certain time.

In general however, fixed-time delays are fragile and depend a lot on the system on which the test is executed (and the load of the system). A better approach might be to use the [`waitFor`](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#waitFor-function) function to wait for some condition.

For instance, this code acquires a reference to a `QPushButton` object with the text `OK` and then suspends test execution until the buttom becomes disabled:

```
button = waitForObject("{type='QPushButton' text='OK'}")
waitFor(lambda: not button.enabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sleep function. For example to put the script sleep for 2 seconds . (Eg:- sleep(2)). Dont forget to import datatime libraries . (Eg:- import time)

Answer (score 0):

```
# going to sleep for 2 seconds
snooze(2)
```